# How to retrieve the value of a dynamic property in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using .net core with ef core and I'm trying to dynamically retrieve a property from an object.

Eg, if I have an object called "Report" as follows:

```
public class Report
{
    public string ReportQuestion1 { get; set; }
    public string ReportQuestion2 { get; set; }
    public string ReportQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

How do I do the equivalent of this:

```
var report = _reportRepository.Get(id);

var x = "ReportQuestion2"

var y = report.x
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Reflection`.

```
var y = report.GetType().GetProperty(x).GetValue(report, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed